# bathroom vent not working correctly

Tags: bathroom, vent

Had some mildew on the ceiling so I thought some thing was wrong with the exhaust sucking the moisture from the shower. So I vacuumed everything and removed the flapper and cleaned that as well.So I put everything back together and turn the vent on and instead of the flapper opening to suck up the moisture it being sucked close by the exhaust.I tried flipping the flapper around and it can only go 1 way.Its a fantech model PBH4 ceiling vent.Plenty of suction.Just the flapper is not opening like it should its being suck close. Any suggestions?Thanks

Comment: A photo would be helpful but it sounds like you have the damper (flapper)on the wrong side of the flange.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm pretty sure @EdBeal is right, but if you could add a picture or two to your question it might let us help you further. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.